# Haskell: numbering items inside a list

Tags: list, haskell, numbers

I am trying to number items inside a list according to their order relative to a preceding element, like "book" in the list below.

```
  myList=["book","book","title","author","title","book","title","book", "author"]
```

I would like to have:

```
[book 1, book 2, title 2.1, author 2.1, title 2.2, book 3, title 3.1, book 4, author 4.1]
```

The count restarts at 1 for "title" and "author" after a new "book" is met.
I can eazily number the books but I don't know how to number the other items depending on the book number.

so I tried to combine a zip in a list comprehension, like this:

```
zip [fst (head (zip[1..][x | x <- myList, x=="book"]))..][x | x <- myList, x=="title" || x=="author"]
```

but what I got is:

```
 [(1,"title"),(2,"author"),(3,"title"),(4,"title"),(5,"author")]
```

It doesn't matter if the result is a tuple or a list.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
omar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an auxiliary function to keep track of the counting variables:

```
number xs = number' 0 0 xs
number' n m (x:xs) | x == "book" = (x,n+1,0) : number' (n+1) 0 xs
number' n m (x:xs) | otherwise = (x,n,m+1) : number' n (m+1) xs
number' _ _ [] = []
```

Comment: as a follow up question. I tried to convert the list of tuples into a list of lists like this: map (\(a, b, c) -> [a, b, c]) [("book",1, 0)....] And I get the following error msg:  No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ....The numbers cause the problem because with tuples of strings only, the conversion works fine. Any idea why? Thanks again

Comment: Lists in haskell are homogenous and don't support mixing of different types.

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions for accumulating over lists. In this case, we want something like `map` except we need to carry along information from the previous elements. A function that does this is `scanl :: (s -> a -> s) -> s -> [a] -> [s]`.

You are better accumulating a pair of integers than a float. Floats are imprecise and so you'll likely end up with something other than you wanted. Lets say `s = (Int, Int)` and create the step function.

```
step :: (Int, Int) -> String -> (Int, Int)
step (a, b) s@"book"   = (a + 1, 0    )
step (a, b) s@"title"  = (a    , b + 1)
step (a, b) s@"author" = (a    , b + 1)
step x      _          = x
```

When we see `"book"` we add `1` to the left integer and set the right integer to `0`. When we see `"title"` or `"author"` we add `1` to the right integer and leave the left integer the same. Otherwise, we leave both integers the same. You can modify this as needed.

```
scanl step (0, 0) myList
= [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(4,0),(4,1)]
```

We need to do two final things. First, `scanl` produces the initial state as a first element but we do not want it. This is easily dropped with `tail` or `drop 1` (`tail` is okay because `scanl` always produces a non-empty list, but many would prefer to see `drop 1` anyways). Secondly, we want to augment each tuple with the appropriate string.

```
zipWith (\s (a, b) -> (s, a, b)) <*> drop 1 . scanl step (0, 0)
```

If you are not familiar with `<*>` it is `(<*>) f g x = f x (g x)` (in this case). We could have also written:

```
\xs -> zipWith (\s (a, b) -> (s, a, b)) xs ((drop 1 . scanl step (0, 0)) xs)
```